# jQgrid Toolbar search, add clear search button next to search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, toolbar

I am new in jQgrid coding. I have implemented Toolbar searching in my jQGrid. In that I want to add clear search button or you can say RESET button next to search textbox like this [image]
 How I achieve this??? I search a lot about this on internet but I didn't found something relevant to achieve this. I am using jQgrid 4.4.4 & jQuery 1.8.3.

Answer (score 3):

You should update jqGrid to the last version 4.5.4. It has implemented the feature which you need. New property `clearSearch: false` in `colModel` can be used to *remove* clear search button in some columns.

Comment: I was waiting of your comment sir & thanx for comment. But because of few circumstances I can't upgrade my JQgrid. If I want to do this in my current jQgrid version.... then It is possible???

Comment: @Rahul: Sorry, but I don't see any simple way to do this. Implementation `clearSearch` feature follow changing the structure of every element in the searching bar. It's a `<table>` now which contains up to 3 columns. The last column is the column with "clear search button". The searching module is changed and some lines of `ui.jqgrid.css` are changed too.

Comment: @Rahul: It's clear that it's probably possible to include [grid.filter.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.filter.js) from the last version of jqGrid *after* `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` so that it's overwrite `grid.filter.js` part of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. You will have to add some CSS stiles from new version of `ui.jqgrid.css` too. It will be a lot of things to do and you will spend many time in debugging. jqGrid 4.5.4 contains many other improvements. I'd recommend you to consider to migrate your solution to new version of jqGrid.

Comment: Ok sir, Thanx for such a useful suggestion & I will surely concentrate on your suggestion. Keep supporting like this...

Comment: Oleg: One more question I want ask that, so now because of jQgrid version; there is no possibility to add search operators like clear search button???

Comment: @Rahul: You are welcome! Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean in the last sentence of your last comment: "there is no possibility to add search operators like clear search button???". jqGrid have only `clearToolbar` method which you can call, but it clears *full* searching toolbar and reloads the grid without any filter. You can use `beforeClear` to stop reloading, but that's all is not what you need probably.

Comment: I mean to say, I also wanted to show search operators for example eq, ne, cn etc. on left side of each search box. Is that possible to with my current version jQgrid.

Comment: @Rahul: No. The feature is not exist in jqGrid 4.4.4. I wrote about the table with 3 columns inside of every cell on searching toolbar. The first column is the searching operation, the second is the main input or select element and the last column contains "clear button". The functionality are introduced in version [4.5.0](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:change#addition_and_changes1). jqGrid 4.5.4 contains many additionaly bug fixes. I can repeat that I don't see any simple way to use the functionality in jqGrid 4.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#delete-button').click(function(){
   $('#input-field').val("");
});
```

Here is an example **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6UD9V/1/)**

Comment: Thanx for the reply. But I want button inside inside column next to search textbox. And I don't think your would achieve this because its asp.net button code.